# How can i validate and exit QInputDialog?

Tags: python, validation, user-interface, input, pyqt4

```
...
Textbox = QtGui.QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Get Name', 
            'Enter  Name:')
        Text =Texbox[0]
Textbox2 = QtGui.QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Get Surname', 
            'Enter  Surname:')
        Text2 =Texbox2[0]
...
```

I am using python 3.3 with pyqt4. When making a GUI, i am asking the user to enter specific details using multiple popup dialog boxes within a function, however when nothing is entered into the box it will accept such value, instead of asking the user to reenter. There is also the option to close the dialog box (the exit button in the top right), however when this is clicked the next dialog box will run instead of stop the entire function. 
I want the dialog boxes to stop running when the exit button is activated, and the dialog box to not allow no vlaues being entered. If any other information is needed please let me know.

Comment: what do you mean by **stop running**? to crash?

Comment: Yes, as the information inserted by the user it is stored within my sqlite database, so I don't want any information being stored when I close the dialog box (or entering empty values). However I do not want the end my whole program as I will have other parts of my GUI running while these dialog boxes are in use (such as the page linking to these boxes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a form for gathering this information. You can have a dialog that look like code below. This code might not be exactly what you need, but sure point you the right direction.

[image]

here is the code (generated using QtDesigner an [pyuic4](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/designer.html#pyuic4))

**Note:** *Automatically generated internationalization's stuff were removed for making the example briefest.*

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(371, 113)
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtGui.QGridLayout(Dialog)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtGui.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.gridLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.buttonBox = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(Dialog)
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.buttonBox, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox, QtCore.SIGNAL("accepted()"), Dialog.accept)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox, QtCore.SIGNAL("rejected()"), Dialog.reject)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I have adapted to validating my qinput dialog boxes, when I enter no information the box will just reappear (and won't skip to the next dialog box). Note, I have kept sperate dialog boxes for both name and surname (one pops up at a time). However when I click 'cancel' or 'exit' I will be introduced with the next dialog box instead of all of the dialog boxes not running, which is what I want.